# Manipulation of Matrix in Python: Adding the values to the right and bottom of an element to that element

Tags: python, matrix

I'm very new to coding so please bear with me.

Lets say I have a 2d list `M = [[3, 0, 2, 18],[-1, 1, 3, 4],[-2, -3, 18, 7]]` means to symbolise a matrix

```
[3, 0, 2, 18]
[-1, 1, 3, 4]
[-2, -3, 18, 7]
```

I would like the find the compiled value (CV) of each element by adding the values by adding the values to the right and bottom of an element to that element

so for example

CV[2,3] gives me 7 + 0 + 0 = 7 as there are no elements to its right and bottom

CV[1,3] gives me 4 + 7 + 0 = 11 as there is no cell to its right

CV[2,2] gives me 18 + 0 + 7 = 25

CV[1,2] gives me 1 + 25 + 11 = 39

a solved matrix would be

[216, 132, 70, 29]

[81,  62,  39, 11]

[20,  22,  25,  7]

How would I find out the CV of [0,0]? I have managed to find out the CV of the base row, but after that it gets way too messy. Is there a better way to do this? I am looking for both an iterative and recursive way. Thank you!

````
def cv_iterative(m):
    #first row
    matrixnew = []
    total = 0
    base = reversed(m[len(m) - 1])
    baseresult = (list(accumulate(base)))
    basenew = []
    for i in baseresult:
        basenew.append(i)
    basenew = reversed(basenew)
    matrixnew.append(list(basenew))```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjIk2.png
````

Comment: Please share your expected output

Comment: take a look at [numpy.](http://www.numpy.org/) If you ever need to work with matrices, you want numpy.

Comment: my expected output would be CV[0,0] = 216

Comment: unfortunately this is for a basic python course and we are not expected (or supposed to) to use numpy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def cv_iterative(m):    
    for i in range(1, len(m)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(m[-i])+1):

            s = m[-i][-j]

            if j != 1:
                s += m[-i][-j+1]
            if i != 1:
                s += m[-i+1][-j]

            m[-i][-j] = s

    return m

M = [[3, 0, 2, 18],[-1, 1, 3, 4],[-2, -3, 18, 7]]
CV = cv_iterative(M)
print(CV)
print(CV[0][0])
```

If you want to only get `216`, write `return m[0][0]` instead of `return m` and then:

```
M = [[3, 0, 2, 18],[-1, 1, 3, 4],[-2, -3, 18, 7]]
print(cv_iterative(M))
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. May I ask what is the function of "s" and the significance of the negative signs in m[-i][-j]?

Comment: Negative signs iterate through list from the last to the first. ِAny time, any element `m[-i][-j]` should added with values in the right and bottom of it. I assign the element to `s` and then add other elements to it.But for example `m[-1][-2]` (18) hasn't any element in bottom of it. For this problem I wrote two if_statement. In case that `i = 1` and `j = 2` ---> `m[-1][-2] = 18`, `j` is not `1` so first `if` execute and `m[-1][-1]` (7) adds to 18. But second `if` doesn't execute.

Comment: Thank you! And why did you add "m[-i][-j] = s"  after the "if" statements? How is this different from "s = m[-i][-j]" before the "if" statements?

Comment: `s = m[-i][-j]` and `m[-i][-j] = s` aren't equal. In the first we assign one element of list to `s` and then add to `s` other two elements, but in second we place `s` in a certain index of list. For example we pass 18 to `s` and add 7 to it, `s = 25`, and then place 25 instead of 18 (m[-1][-2]).